# How to set up Dynamic multi level filters in Tableau?

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I have a SQL database connected to Tableau desktop.

I'm creating a view with A and B data fields as filters. A has values like "a", "b" ,"c" etc.

Now, I want to achieve this functionality. When I select "a" in filter, how to show only those values in filter of B that have value "a" in A column?

For this I can create a field specifying to show only specific values when I click a particular value like "a" in filter of A.

For example, when click on "a", show ["1","2", "3"] of B. But this approach works only when B values does not change for a value of A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just drag and drop both dimensions into filters card. Make "A" as context filter or you can try with normal filter too and click on "**Show Filter**" for B dimension and make show filter. Now, click on "**Only Relevant Values**" for B filter.